# How to use SMTP Auth in C?

Tags: c, sockets, email, smtp, openssl

I'm trying to do a simple connection to a SMTP server (that requires authentification).
I'm connected to smtp.live.com on port 587 using SSL (the OpenSSL library in C).

I first initialize my socket with the socket() function, then connect to the server with connect(). Then I launch the SSL channel and then I try to login.

Here's the output on my shell :

```
server : 220 BLU0-SMTP261.phx.gbl Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 6.0.3790.4675     ready at  Sat, 9 Mar 2013 07:25:17 -0800 

EHLO [127.0.0.1]
server : 250-BLU0-SMTP261.phx.gbl Hello [163.5.221.45]
250-TURN
250-SIZE 41943040
250-ETRN
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8bitmime
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250-VRFY
250-TLS
250-STARTTLS
250 OK

STARTTLS
server : 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready

EHLO [127.0.0.1]
server : 250-BLU0-SMTP261.phx.gbl Hello [163.5.221.45]
250-TURN
250-SIZE 41943040
250-ETRN
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8bitmime
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250-VRFY
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
250 OK

AUTH LOGIN
server : 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6

Y2hlcmGhvdXXXXXXXXXXXuY29tXHJcbg0K
serveur : 
U2hsYWXXXXXXXXXXXwblxyXG4NCg0K
server :
```

As you can see, the username and the password are both encode in base64 (without \r\n). I don't understand why the server doesn't answer anything... (I tried to put a sleep() before reading the socket , but i got the same result)

Code to connect to the server :

```
static int              _connect_IPV4(int socket, struct hostent *host)
{
  struct sockaddr_in    addr;

  addr.sin_port = htons(587);
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr.sin_addr = *(struct in_addr *)host->h_addr;
  bzero(&addr.sin_zero, 8);
  if (connect(socket, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == -1)
    printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
  else
    return (socket);
}
```

Code to start SSL:

```
static void     _launch_ssl(int socket)
{
  read_socket(socket);
  write_socket(socket, "EHLO [127.0.0.1]\r\n");
  read_socket(socket);
  write_socket(socket, "STARTTLS\r\n");
  read_socket(socket);
}
```

Code to connect SSL:

```
connection      *ssl_connect()
{
  connection    *c;

  c = malloc(sizeof(connection));
  c->ssl_handle = NULL;
  c->ssl_context = NULL;
  c->socket = connect_TCP_IP();
  _launch_ssl(c->socket);
  if (c->socket != -1)
    {
      SSL_load_error_strings();
      SSL_library_init();

      SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
      SSL_new(c->ssl_context);
      SSL_set_fd(c->ssl_handle, c->socket);
      SSL_connect(c->ssl_handle);
    }
  return (c);
}
```

Main :

```
int             main()
{
  connection    *c;

  c = ssl_connect();
  ssl_write_socket(c, "EHLO [127.0.0.1]\r\n");
  ssl_read_socket(c);
  ssl_write_socket(c, "AUTH LOGIN\r\n");
  ssl_read_socket(c);
  ssl_write_socket(c, "Y2hlcmNoZXN0b3lhQGhvdG1haWwuY29tXHJcbg0K");
  printf("\n");
  ssl_read_socket(c);
  ssl_write_socket(c, "U2hsYWdldHRvUHIwblxyXG4NCg0K");
  printf("\n");
  ssl_read_socket(c);
}
```

Comment: You need to show us your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I hope you intend to improve your client so that it actually reacts to what the server sends. For example, it looks like in your `_launch_ssl` function you do not actually check the server's reply to `EHLO` to make sure `STARTTLS` is offered as an option before you attempt to use it. The pseudocode of that function should be:

1. send EHLO (preferably not with something meaningless like [127.0.0.1]!)
2. check the server's reply
3. if STARTTLS is not among the options offered, bail
4. if STARTTLS is among the options offered, send STARTTLS and continue.

Similarily, in `main()`, you need to check after `EHLO` that the server has actually responded 250, and check after `AUTH` that the server has actually responded 334.

Otherwise, the problem seems to be that you don't send `\r\n` after your responses. In other words:

```
ssl_write_socket(c, "Y2hlcmNoZXN0b3lhQGhvdG1haWwuY29tXHJcbg0K");
```

should be:

```
ssl_write_socket(c, "Y2hlcmNoZXN0b3lhQGhvdG1haWwuY29tXHJcbg0K\r\n");
```

Furthermore, your base64 string contains an `\\r\\n\r\n` (backslash + 'r' + backslash + 'n' + CR + LF) embedded *inside the string* as though the `\\r\\n\r\n` were part of the username. Assuming that's wrong, then, in fact, your code should probably actually read:

```
ssl_write_socket(c, "Y2hlcmNoZXN0b3lhQGhvdG1haWwuY29t\r\n");
```